# Node.JS where's the ChangeLog the describes v0.4.4 and 0.4.5

Tags: node.js, changelog

The ChangeLogs I have seen stop at 0.4.3 or 0.4.2. Does anybody know if there is a changelog that includes the most recent versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the most recent changelog in https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.4.5/ChangeLog (I don't know why it is not updated in the master branch). The changelogs are also posted in the [blog](http://blog.nodejs.org/) and the mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

- [v0.4.4](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/26/node-v0-4-4/)
- [v0.4.5](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/04/02/node-v0-4-5/)